# Random HTTP error 405 while using ajax request

Tags: ajax, http-post, contact-form, http-error

I am getting HTTP error 405 verb not allowed. As sometimes code works and sometimes throws http 405 error, I need to understand whether this is programming problem or server configuration problem. I am using ajax with jquery. I have gone through  all related posts here and tried all recommended options related with the code. Please help.

my javascript code is as follows

```
$(function() {
$('.error').hide();
$(".button").click(function() {
        // validate and process form
        // first hide any error messages
           $('.error').hide();
          var name = $("input#name").val();
    if (name == "") {
  $("label#name_error").show();
  $("input#name").focus();
  return false;
                            }
    var email = $("input#email").val();
    if (email == "") {
  $("label#name_error").show();
    $("input#email").focus();
  return false;
                             }

  var textquery = $("textarea#textquery").val();
    if (textquery == "") {
  $("label#name_error").show();
  $("textarea#textquery").focus();
  return false;
                                 }

    var dataString = name + email +  textquery;
//  alert (dataString);return false;

    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "samplemail.aspx",
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {
    $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
    $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form <br> Submitted!</h2>")
    .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(1500, function() {
      $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
                             });
                       }
        });
return false;
});
});
runOnLoad(function(){
  $("input#name").select().focus();
                     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved
the way Of passing parameter was wrong i.e.data : datastring . 
The correct way is data : { name : name, email: email, textquery: textquery}